# how to upgrade joomla1.5 to joomla3.4 along with virutemart 1.1.9 to virtuemart 2

Tags: joomla, virtuemart

I've successfully upgraded joomla website from J1.2.26 to J3.4. But My virtuemart data is still in j1.1.26 and not migrated to j3.4. I've installed vm2 in joomla3.4, and also upgraded vm1.1.9 to vm2.0 within joomla1.2 site. 
can you please tell me what steps should i take to move data too to the newely installed joomla 3.4.

The following method i used..

- backuped my website as offline
- current website is in joomla 1.5.26 using vm1.1.9.
- installed vm2
- upgraded vm with data, it is successful
- installed a new joomla instance of new version 3.4.8
- installed virtuemart 2.
- installed redMigrator
- imported data from joomla1.5 site to this new site using
  redMigrator but no virtuemart data is transferred.

I'm really stuck here.. no website is helping.. everyone is saysing..
here is the method of upgrading joomla...
here is the method of upgrading virtuemart.. nobody is telling the way as combine..

Answer (score 0):

Well you could transfer the tables manually in PHPmyadmin for example and see if it gets you where you want to be.